# Why does my new Macbook Pro ship with Mavericks instead of Yosemite?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos

Why does my new Macbook Pro ship with Mavericks instead of Yosemite even after ordering it after the release of Yosemite?

Comment: Was it a Build-To-Order, or just the stock configuration? I ordered one the day of the release that was customized and am hoping it comes with Mavericks so I can upgrade after Yosemite has gone through a few bug-fix updates.

Comment: I thought the same but when am paying 2200$ for a mac book pro, i expect yosemite to be natively builtin and moreover i waited for 4 months for this and i ordered the day when tim cook said yosemite will be available. Also, i customized the order cause one of the apple reps said that if we do it there is a possibility of new os to be built in. When exactly should i order inorder to get yosemite natively builtin?

Comment: Chill out. Installing Yosemite takes a whopping hour (tops) and it's completely free.

Answer (score 10):

Unless it was a BTO (Built-To-Order), it's likely coming out of a warehouse or shipping container that was packed pre-Yosemite and those boxes aren't opened to update the OS.

Yosemite is a free upgrade, so just upgrade the OS when you first power up the machine and there won't be any difference between your system and one that left the factory with Yosemite.

There should be no "performance lag" due to an upgrade vs. clean install, especially for a fresh-out-of-the-box system but if you're worried, this site has all sorts of questions and answers on how to erase and then install Yosemite.